# Django: Aggregate a Raw SQL with LEFT JOIN, NO Foreign Keys, AND inject to DetailView (context)

Tags: mysql, django, aggregate, detailview, rawsql

I have been revamping my webapp with Django 1.7. It has been a lot of fun... and tears and blood!

Thing is I've been struggling for the last few days to do a simple LEFT JOIN to aggregate some values from a table with no FKs. The query result should go to a Class View (DetailView). Believe me that I have searched and searched for an answer in the entire web (including the World Wide Web) to no avail.

You might ask why is it that my tables have no Foreign Keys? Well, the original database design hadn't any and now the tables hold hundreds of millions of rows. I could add FK constraints but that would be costly, but it would brake things, and would require to remake entire scripts that do extraction and loading!

I thought falling back to the good old [raw SQL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-queries) because, according to Django,

> raw() has a bunch of other options that make it very powerful...

Yeah, right. The truth is **model.objects.raw()** that its power is limited and it doesn't work for what I want to do (it just doesn't aggregate).

**Tables/Models (simplified)**

```
Table `customer` (customer_id, order_id) 

Table `order` (order_id, order_name)
```

**MySQL/Django query (simplified)**

```
'SELECT a.order_id, SUM(a.order_value) 
FROM order a 
LEFT JOIN customer b 
ON a.order_id = b.order_id 
WHERE b.customer_id = %s', [customer_id]
```

It looks so innocent, right? Hell no! It's a Django nightmare! Of course, I could easily do that in Django with a **__set**, but alas, I don't have FKs.

On top of my problem I am trying to add aggregates to a context in my DetailView template. So I tried hacking it with **View()** and made a function inside my DetailView custom class:

```
def NewContextFTW():
    # here get the freaking queryset in my own terms
    return myhighlycomplexqueryset
```

And then in template:

```
{% for rows in view.NewContextFTW %}
    {{rows.id}}
    {{rows.sum_order_value}}
{% endfor %}
```

...but it failed.

**Edit:**
I found a solution today! And I want to share the love to the world! See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

This solution solved my problem. Hope it solves yours too.

Override **get_context_data**, execute SQL directly through a connection, convert resulting list into a dictionary, add it to context, enjoy:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    # get context from the class this very function belongs to
    context = super(MyClassView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    user = self.user # example

    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT a.order_id, SUM(a.order_value) FROM order a LEFT JOIN customer b ON a.order_id = b.order_id WHERE b.customer_id = %s', [user])
    d = dictfetchall(cursor)

    new_object_list = []
    for i in range(len(d)):
        order_id = d[i]['order_id']
        sum_order_value = d[i]['SUM(a.order_value)']
        row = aggregated_row(order_id, sum_order_value)
        new_object_list.append(row)

    context['aggregated_values'] = new_object_list
    return  context
```

To make that work don't forget to:

```
from django.views.generic import DetailView
from django.db import connection
```

...then define the following function to convert the list into a dictionary (this boilerplate comes from Django's 1.7 own documentation):

```
def dictfetchall(cursor):
    "Returns all rows from a cursor as a dict"
    desc = cursor.description
    return [
        dict(zip([col[0] for col in desc], row))
        for row in cursor.fetchall()
    ]
```

...create a class to hold your rows as objects:

```
 class aggregated_row(object):
    def __init__(self, order_id, sum_order_value):
        self.order_id = order_id
        self.sum_order_value = sum_order_value
```

...and last but not least, the template:

```
{% for rows in aggregated_values%}
        <tr>
                <td>{{rows.order_id}}</td>
                <td>{{rows.sum_order_value}}</td>
        </tr>

{% endfor %}
```